# cobalt does not handle KEY_BACKSPACE in updated youtube tv search page

Tags: cobalt

With the update of the youtube tv search page, the KEY_BACKSPACE seems not functional anymore. The KEY_BACKSPACE is intended to clear previous text in the search text field. The KEY_BACKSPACE still works on chrome. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Thanks for the report! Note that the best way to report issues with Cobalt is to file them at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=181120. This way you'll be able to see the progress and have a follow-up conversation.

Answer (score 0):

We're looking at this issue on our YouTube server side. https://youtube.com/tv

Comment: Also it is no longer possible to search for a video based on the video tag